# Typo3 max image size for content elements

Tags: image, element, typo3, typoscript

I try to set the max image size for a specific content element. How can I do this for the element "content"? I tried to combine several options, but nothing works.
Is the content.maxImageWidthInText.maxH the right way?

Here is my code:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    typeNum = 0            
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {

      file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
      file.stdWrap.cObject {

        key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
        key.override.field = backend_layout

        default = TEXT
        default.value = fileadmin/templates/index.html

        1 = TEXT
        1.value = fileadmin/templates/index.html    

      }  

      variables {

        # Content
        content < styles.content.get
        content.select.where = colPos=0
        content.maxImageWidthInText.maxW = 135                          
        .....
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the registers `maxImageWidth` and `maxImageWidthInText` to do that:

```
content = COA
content {
    10 = LOAD_REGISTER
    10 {
        maxImageWidth = 135
        maxImageWidthInText = 100
    }

    20 < styles.content.get

    30 = RESTORE_REGISTER
}
```

Couldn't find any official documentation though - you can find this stuff using the TypoScript object browser.

Comment: Perfect. And how can i do this for more than one content element? i have tree parts of content areas and different image sizes.

Comment: You can use this in any place you fetch content elements from the database. So if you have another `CONTENT` object somewhere (e.g. a styles.content.getRight), just wrap it like the `styles.content.get`. You can use different values for the registers each time. If it does not work, check if an extension modifies the TS of `tt_content.image` somewhere.